# Kivy build up an enormous sized APK file

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

**UPDATE:** If you are using the Kivy Virtual Machine from the Official website, if you want to save yourself from a bunch of errors, do Not create 'Shared Folder' and build in it, instead create a new folder inside the VM and build it from there. It works

I just finished building up an Apk file using Kivy. Its the most basic app that it could ever get, just a Button displaying the text 'Hello World' and it ended up building an APK file of 866 MB, yes that's correct. I just followed the instructions for buildozer for python3 support [on the official page here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/buildozer)

and that's it.

Comment: This usually results from including something you didn't intend in the apk, such as the previous version of the apk. Check what files you are including.

Comment: @inclement Hi! I didn't change any of the defaults for inclusions in the buildozer.spec file, it says to include kv files, python files and png. I've infact made almost no changes in the spec file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to also exclude some folders so that they dont get bundled up when buildozer starts to create an apk.so do check the .spec file to add some excludes